# Two UIView Controllers - changing View controllers - touching top of Second View Controller changes back to first view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a storyboard with two UIVIewControllers.
They both have ID's set and when "Start Game" is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender{
    [self startGameProcedure];
    UIViewController *gameController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
    [self presentViewController:gameController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This loads the second view controller.
But when the user touches anywhere in the top half of this view controller, it goes back to the first view controller? I don't want this to happen.
What have I done incorrectly and how can I resolve this please?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of how this second viewcontroller looks like? Or what startGameProcedure does?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans startGameProcedure just sets a few integers and timers, the view controller just has a title at the top, a trivia question in the middle, and a correct and incorrect button at the bottom, nothing special at all. I'm confused as to why its changing views.

Comment: It previously had a segue going from the first view to the 2nd, but I have clicked on the segue and deleted it, but its still changing views when the view is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the transition style being "Partial Curl".
Changing this resolved the issue.